# inventory manage system not working on edit order magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I am editing an order and item have not saleable quantity and message showing **The requested qty is not available** but if i click on submit order then new order is created and previous order not cancelled also.
Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

I have download same version from magento website and configure it then check and found same issue in fresh setup.
Please help if anybody have solution for it.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check below possibility

1. You can't decrease or edit qty in cart/order/invoice/shipment.
2. please check product qty.

I think issue will resolve with this.